# Pandas dividing rows from 2 df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, division

Is it to perform rows division between 2 dfs by matching columns. For example,

df1:

```
Name    1    2   3   5  Total
-----------------------------
A       2    2   2   2   8
B       1    1   1   1   4
C       0    1   2   3   6
```

df2:

```
Alias   1    2   3   4  Total
-----------------------------
X       5    5   5   5  20
Y       10   10  0   0  20
Z       1    2   3   4  10
```

The result would be:

r

```
NewName 1    2     3     4     5   Total   
----------------------------------------        (These rows will be set manually) 
I       2/5   2/5   2/5   0/5   -   8/20    <---I = A/X 
J       1/5   1/5   1/5   0/5   -   4/20    <---J = B/X
K       1/10  1/10   -     -    -   4/20    <---K = B/Y 
L       0/5   1/5   2/5   0/5   -   6/20    <---L = C/X
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: What determines the corresponding rows upon which division is done?

Comment: I would like to control that manually

Comment: This should probably be in the question itself, then.

Comment: If you want to match positionally, you can use np.divide(df1.values, df2.values)

Comment: I think the 4th column should also be full of nulls? Since, the 4th and 5th columns have no equivalents in the corresponding dataframes (see my answer).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yep it can be null too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs an involved solution, but can be done. First, declare your manually controlled parameters.

```
i = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
j = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'X']
k = ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
```

Now, the idea is to align the two dataframes.

```
x = df1.set_index('Name')
y = df2.set_index('Alias')

x, y = x.align(y)
```

Perform division, and create a new dataframe. Since we're dividing numpy arrays, you might encounter runtime warnings. Ignore them.

```
z = x.reindex(i, axis=0).values / y.reindex(j, axis=0).values   

df = pd.DataFrame(z, index=k, columns=x.columns)
df

     1    2         3   4   5  Total
I  0.4  0.4  0.400000 NaN NaN    0.4
J  0.2  0.2  0.200000 NaN NaN    0.2
K  0.1  0.1       inf NaN NaN    0.2
L  0.0  0.2  0.400000 NaN NaN    0.3
```

Edit; on older versions, `reindex` does not accept an `axis` parameter. In that case, use

```
z = x.reindex(index=i).values / y.reindex(index=j).values
```

---

Additionally, to fill up non-finite values, use `np.isfinite` -

```
df[np.isfinite(df)].fillna('-')

     1    2    3  4  5  Total
I  0.4  0.4  0.4  -  -    0.4
J  0.2  0.2  0.2  -  -    0.2
K  0.1  0.1    -  -  -    0.2
L  0.0  0.2  0.4  -  -    0.3
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED columns = c?  where does c come from?
I also got this error:  TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"

Comment: @TylerNG Whoops, sorry, it was an artifact of debugging. Take a look now.

Comment: @TylerNG That error.... it's because you're on an older version. Use `index=j` and `index=i` and remove the axis param.

Comment: @TylerNG Basically, `x.reindex(index=i).values / y.reindex(index=j).values` Which is the way of doing it before v0.21.

Comment: awesome as always!

Answer (score 1):

```
I = df1.T['A']/df2.T['X']
J = df1.T['B']/df2.T['X']
K = df1.T['B']/df2.T['Y'] 
L = df1.T['C']/df2.T['X']

df = pd.concat([I, J, K, L], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'I', 1:'J', 2:'K', 3:'L'}).T
```

Then, to make it look more like the output you wanted:

```
df[np.isfinite(df)].fillna('-')
```

--

*Edit*

More universally, to not cascade divisions, you can do:

```
pairs = [('A','X'), ('B','X'), ('B','Y'), ('C','X')]
series_to_concat = [df1.T[col_df1]/df2.T[col_df2] for (col_df1, col_df2) in pairs]
names = ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
col_names = {col_num : name for col_num, name in enumerate(names)}

df = pd.concat(series_to_concat, axis=1).rename(columns=col_names).T
```

Comment: This is hyper specific to the sample data shown here.

Comment: You can put `('A','X')` etc. tuples in a single list and then do list comprehension, if you want to be more "universal". Am I wrong to think that this answer will work for any simillar `df` as long as the columns are provided correctly (of course names also have to be provided, but it is not the big issue here)?

Comment: You can implement a solution as you please, but if the goal is simplicity and readability, then you'd be defeating the purpose ;-)

Comment: I am not sure what is problem here? I see you implying it's not simple nor readable? It's basically setup (which has to be done somehow) + quite clear oneliner.

Comment: The problem is that you are cascading 4 separate division operations, and then claiming that you can simplify that with a loop. All I'm saying is that it isn't the best way to go about things. I'm just giving you feedback, nothing more.

Comment: I have never suggested the loop.

Comment: `You can put ('A','X') etc. tuples in a single list and then do list comprehension` What is a list comprehension, if not a loop?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don't care about indices so this should work.

```
r = df1.reset_index(drop=True) / df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks but this would works if all the positions match in both dfs.  However, mine don't since I need to divide by some specific rows in both dfs.

Comment: Why didn't you say so?

Comment: sorry for the confusion